# how to make any filter's value that accept integer value be a function of the timestamp in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

For example, i am trying to apply blur effect to video in ffmpeg using gblur filter, i want the blur strength to gradually increase from 0 to 50 in 2 secs starting at 5 secs and fade back from 50 to 0 in 3 secs thus finishing at 15 secs. In summary the blur is between 5 and 15 secs but from 5 to 7, the effect will gradually grow from 0 to 50 and from 12 to 15 it will fade from 50 back to 0.

here is what i tried :

```
ffmpeg -i test-video.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i test-image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]gblur=sigma='if( lte(t,5) + gte(t, 15), 0, if( between(t, 7, 12), 50, min( max(25t - 125, 0), max(-16.67t + 250, 0) ) ) )':enable='between(t,5,15)'[bg];[1:v]fade=in:0:30[ol];[ol]fps=fps=15[ol];[bg][ol]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,5,15)'[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a output_video.mp4
```

Expectations:

> [0:v]gblur=sigma='if( lte(t,5) + gte(t, 15), 0, if( between(t, 7, 12), 50, min( max(25t - 125, 0), max(-16.67t + 250, 0) ) ) )':enable='between(t,5,15)'[bg]:

The blur strength depends dynamically on the time (t) as described above, controlled by the expression. The enable parameter ensures that this filter is only applied between 5 and 15 seconds.

> [1:v]fade=in:0:30[ol]: [ol]fps=fps=15[ol]: [bg][ol]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,5,15)'[out]:

The overlay input should be faded in for 2 secs starting from 5secs and will last 10secs (same time for the blur)

As result, i am getting Invalid char error. Seems like sigma does not accept the "t" timestamp variable.